# Make words clickable using GUILayout

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a text file which I can read in Unity. I divide the whole text string by words and I want to make each word into a button. To achieve this I want to use GUILayout. This is my code until now

```
//Show text
    GUILayout.BeginArea(new Rect(0, 300, Screen.width, Screen.height));

    GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
    GUILayout.FlexibleSpace();
    for(int i=0; i<dialogLines.Length; i++){
        GUILayout.Button(dialogLines[i]);
    }
    GUILayout.EndHorizontal();
    GUILayout.EndArea();
```

This works correctly and transforms each word into a button. The only problem is that ALL the buttons will only be put in a horizontal line:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/c40pt.png

I need all the horizontal row to start a new line at some point so that all the buttons together would show up as a page with text. Something like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8uow.png

How can I achieve this?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried using multiple horizontal control groups? So instead of `i` to `dialogLines.Length` going up to however many words, and doing another loop inside a new horizontal control group from where you left off?

Comment: I guess you are suggesting to break a horizontal group by New Lines. The problem with that is that I need the words to cover the whole width of the screen, breaking them up at a certain value will make them to either break to new lines too soon or too late.

Comment: A perfect example of what I would need is a GUI.Label in which all the words are actual GUI.Button(s).

Comment: Have a look at this one: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/251558/making-part-of-guitext-clickable.html

He's basically assigning the Label style to the buttons.

Comment: That does not help me with anything, I need ALL the words to be buttons, that can be easily achieved, the only thing is that creating a BeginHorizontal will display all these buttons in one single row, it will never go to a new line. If I have 99 words and put them all in a BeginHorizontal they will all just be in one line and eventually fall off the screen. I need something that would automatically begin a new BeginHorizontal when a button touches the width end of the screen. I hope I explained it correctly.

Comment: Could you check whether the length of the horizontal is greater than the screen width, and then start a new horizontal. Something like `if GuiLayout.Width > Screen.Width { EndHorizontal(); BeginHorizontal(); ...`

Comment: As far as I know you cannot do that. There is a GUILayout.Width method, but it is used to give the layout a certain fixed width, it is not a readable variable or anything.